# Problemas con el DNS

Tags: dns

Tengo dos servidores en la misma red  ejemplo www.server.com  y el segundo www.serverdos.com.

El problema es que cuando ingreso al serverdos  me cambia el dominio por la IP publica http://111.111.111.111:81 en la URL.

He buscado en muchos lugares pero no tengo resultados, probé configurando el tipo de host DNS Hostname (A)  no me permite agregar la IP publica con el puerto al que va dirigido 81, así que tuve que usar por 80 redirect para poder direccionar el DNS a mi server.

Comment: ¿Revisaste el `.htaccess` del directorio raíz? Puede que haya una redirección a ese nivel.

Comment: gracis por la respuesta ,  revise mi servidor apache y en ninguno de los dos server hay un directorio .htaccess

Comment: `.htaccess` es un archivo. Revisa el directorio raíz de tu página, ahí debe haber un archivo que se llama así. Es un archivo oculto, por lo que debes activar el visor de archivos ocultos para verlo. Lo abres y revisas las redirecciones. Pero ten cuidado al manipular ese archivo, cualquier error en él hace que la web deje de funcionar.

Comment: habilite la vista de archivos ocultos y busque el .htaccess y no me aparece los mas parecido son estos archivos  https://gyazo.com/b6e3a789b59a4fccac852b12d7a8eba3   :/

Comment: encontré la solucion  no-ip da una opcion que se llama masking , esta opcion  le da solucion al problema  :)  https://gyazo.com/6cc8757733e9d592498072a6b022356c   muchas gracias amigo por tu ayuda

Comment: no-ip da una opción llamada masking la cual remplaza la ip publica por el nombre del host https://gyazo.com/6cc8757733e9d592498072a6b022356c

Comment: A la próxima, aclara dónde tienes el dominio definido.

Comment: podrias agregar la configuracion que tienes en tu dns server???

Comment: Dirijiendo a puerto 81 no es una función de DNS, Si el servidor escucha en un puerto que no es estander, hay que poner el puerto en el URL.  Puede configuar Apache para que pueda regresar archivos diferentes de acuerdo del nombre que el cliente usa.  Por ejemplo, www.hola.com regresa archivos de /var/www/hola y www.chao.com regresa archivos de /var/www/chao.  Pero eso es una función de Apache, no de DNS.